# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 8931 Laravel 5

Tags: post, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am getting an error of MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 8931. It was working fine but suddenly it started throwing this error. I created a view in directory resources/views/main/templates/submit-for-sale.blade.php and defined its route in routes.php as:

```
Route::get('/submit-for-sale', function () {
    return view('main.templates.submit-for-sale');
});
```

This view submit-for-sale.blade.php contains a form whose form tag looks like:

```
 <form id="submit-sale-form" action="{{route('main.submit-sale-form')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal>
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    .............
 </form>
```

View is loading perfectly.

Route to post form in routes.php

```
  Route::post('/submit-sale-form', ['as' => 'main.submit-sale-form', 'uses' => 'MainController@submitSaleForm']);
```

Code in MainController.php

```
  public function submitSaleForm(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = Input::get();
    foreach ([
                 'name' => 'Name',
                 'email' => 'Email',
             ] as $key => $label) {
        if (!isset($parameters[$key]) || empty($parameters[$key])) {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'success' => false,
                    'error'   => "{$label} cannot be empty",
                ]
            );
        }
    }
  }
```

[image]

It worked fine 2 - 3 times same code but suddenly it started throwing this error. Your help and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Does `action="{{route('main.submit-sale-form')}}"` generate the correct uri in your markup?

Comment: Yes. its working fine now. I don't know what happened everything is fine. I just wrote the route again and now its working. Thank you.